# Error : when i use the NDK in the Android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-ndk

my setting as flowing:

1.app/build.gradle

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "demo.kid.com.testjni"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    ndk {
        moduleName "helloNDK"
    }
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

2.i add this "android.useDeprecatedNdk=true" in the "gradle.properties"

3.the NDK path also set and it is correct

4.the c++ source

```
JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL
Java_demo_kid_com_testjni_MainActivity_getStringFromNative
(JNIEnv *env, jobject){
    return env->NewStringUTF("Hello World From the JNI!");
}
```

5.the MainActivity use :

```
static {
    System.loadLibrary("helloNDK");
}
public native String getStringFromNative();
```

6.the eroor informations :

```
    process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, D:/C/IT/android_studio/some/NDK/android-ndk-r11b-windows-x86/android-ndk-r11b/build//../toolchains/aarch64-linux-android-4.9/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/aarch64-linux-android-gcc -MMD -MP -MF D:\C\IT\android_studio\Model\M_testJNI\TestJNI\app\build\intermediates\ndk\debug\obj/local/arm64-v8a/objs/helloNDK/D_\C\IT\android_studio\Model\M_testJNI\TestJNI\app\src\main\jni\helloNDK.o.d -fpic -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector-strong -no-canonical-prefixes -O2 -g -DNDEBUG -fomit-frame-pointer -fstrict-aliasing -funswitch-loops -finline-limit=300 -ID:\C\IT\android_studio\Model\M_testJNI\TestJNI\app\src\main\jni -ID:\C\IT\android_studio\Model\M_testJNI\TestJNI\app\src\debug\jni -ID:/C/IT/android_studio/Model/M_testJNI/TestJNI/app/build/intermediates/ndk/debug -DANDROID -Wa,--noexecstack -Wformat -Werror=format-security -isystem D:/C/IT/android_studio/some/NDK/android-ndk-r11b-windows-x86/android-ndk-r11b/build//../platforms/android-23/arch-arm64/usr/include -c D:\C\IT\android_studio\Model\M_testJNI\TestJNI\app\src\main\jni\helloNDK.c -o D:\C\IT\android_studio\Model\M_testJNI\TestJNI\app\build\intermediates\ndk\debug\obj/local/arm64-v8a/objs/helloNDK/D_\C\IT\android_studio\Model\M_testJNI\TestJNI\app\src\main\jni\helloNDK.o, ...) failed.
make (e=2): 系统找不到指定的文件。
make: *** [D:\C\IT\android_studio\Model\M_testJNI\TestJNI\app\build\intermediates\ndk\debug\obj/local/arm64-v8a/objs/helloNDK/D_\C\IT\android_studio\Model\M_testJNI\TestJNI\app\src\main\jni\helloNDK.o] Error 2
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugNdk'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'D:\C\IT\android_studio\some\NDK\android-ndk-r11b-windows-x86\android-ndk-r11b\ndk-build.cmd'' finished with non-zero exit value 2
```

Comment: What is your `Android.mk` file?

Comment: need the MK file ? i watch the https://software.intel.com/en-us/videos/using-the-ndk-with-android-studio  video, and i follow it to do, he did't use the MK file.

Comment: Yes, you need one.